# Facebook like Button in PHP for an element

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to get a like button on my site to a video rather then the all site....

can't make it happen.... any ideas?

Thanks (and frustrated),

John

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show what you did and what is not working?

Comment: Yes, please give us some more details about what isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If video has its own id (for example you store video data in database or something) you can print the like button's iframe with ?video=video_id at the end of url in the href parameter. So every Like button for every video will be unique. I only code highlighted this part in the code bellow:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fvideo%3Dvideo_id&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

or in fblm case:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://example.com`?video=video_id" show_faces="true" width="450"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Theank you for the quick reply, as you mentioned i have the video in the database, and the video is getting the like button - however on the user wall it states that the user like a link and not a video (same as youtube for an example)

Comment: You only can solve this by making a watchvideo.php that shows only the video by id with the same URL. (can you accept the answer? :) )

Comment: You make a php script that get the video id in $_GET['video_id'] and depends on that it shows the video by id. Only that video. This way when it is liked and clicked on user wall on facebook it goes to the that video.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with the Open Graph you can now share audio and video content too, have a read of the [Like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and the [Open Graph types](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types):

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> 
    <head>
        ...
        [REQUIRED TAGS]
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/awesome.flv" />
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        ...
    </head>
```